# Making a table in Thymeleaf html using nested json data

Tags: html, json, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I got stuck with making a table from json data.

The table i want to make is `the number of visitors of each movie and district`.
And this is a sort of multi-dimensional.
(I am not sure that i call this multi-dimensional table though).

Let's say `row-headers are movies`, `column-headers are districts` and `cells are visitors`.

But i couldn't find out how to put `visitor` cells on proper `<td>` tag.
Specifically, I am not sure the way i made row-headers is proper.

I put all codes below.

Can anybody help me to make that table as what i imagine please?
Please kindly check this out. :<

Thank you alot in advance.

```json
[
  {
    "country":"country 1",
    "districts":[
      {
        "district":"district 1",
        "cinemas":[
          {
            "cinema": "cinema 1",
            "movie":"Sherlock",
            "visitor":30
          },{
            "cinema": "cinema 2",
            "movie":"Terminator",
            "visitor":40
          },{
            "cinema": "cinema 2",
            "movie":"Tarzan",
            "visitor":20
          }]
      }, {
        "district":"district 2",
        "cinemas":[
          {
            "cinema": "cinema 1",
            "movie":"Sherlock",
            "visitor":12
          },{
            "cinema": "cinema 2",
            "movie":"Terminator",
            "visitor":41
          },{
            "cinema": "cinema 2",
            "movie":"Tarzan",
            "visitor":24
          }]
      }, {
        "district":"district 3",
        "cinemas":[
          {
            "cinema": "cinema 1",
            "movie":"Sherlock",
            "visitor":12
          },{
            "cinema": "cinema 2",
            "movie":"Terminator",
            "visitor":41
          }]
      }]
  },    {
  "country":"country 2",
  "districts":[
    {
      "district":"district 1",
      "cinemas":[
        {
          "cinema": "cinema 2",
          "movie":"Terminator",
          "visitor":40
        },{
          "cinema": "cinema 2",
          "movie":"Tarzan",
          "visitor":20
        }]
    }, {
      "district":"district 2",
      "cinemas":[
        {
          "cinema": "cinema 1",
          "movie":"Sherlock",
          "visitor":12
        },{
          "cinema": "cinema 2",
          "movie":"Tarzan",
          "visitor":24
        }]
    }, {
      "district":"district 3",
      "cinemas":[
        {
          "cinema": "cinema 1",
          "movie":"Sherlock",
          "visitor":12
        },{
          "cinema": "cinema 2",
          "movie":"Terminator",
          "visitor":41
        }]
    }]
}
]
```

What the table is supposed to be:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Movies     |country 1                                 | country 2                                       |
           ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |district 1   | district 2  | district 3   | district 1    | district 2    | district 3      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sherlock   | 30          | 12          | 12           | 0             | 12            | 12              |
Terminat   | 40          | 41          | 41           | 40            | 0             | 41              |
Tarzan     | 20          | 24          | 0            | 20            | 24            | 0               |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But what i got is:
[image: Monosnap Hello 2022-11-19 02-08-52]

All codes:

```java
public class Country {

    private String country;
    private List<District> districts;

}
```

```java
public class District {

    private String district;
    private List<Cinema> cinemas;
}
```

```java
public class Cinema {

    String cinema;
    String movie;
    Integer visitor;
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/cinema")
public String getTable(Model model) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File file = Paths.get(CINEMA_FILE_PATH).toFile();

    List<Country> countries = mapper.readValue(file, List.class);

    model.addAttribute("countries", countries);


    return "cinema";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Movies</th>
      <th th:each="country: ${countries}" th:colspan="${country.districts.size()}" th:text="${country.country}" ></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th:block th:each="country: ${countries}">
        <th th:each="district:${country.districts}" th:text="${district.district}"></th>
    </th:block>
  </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="cinema: ${countries.get(0).districts.get(0).cinemas}"> <!-- This is for row-headers, and it might be problem. -->
      <td th:text="${cinema.movie}"></td>
      <th:block th:each="country : ${countries}">
        <th:block th:each="district :${country.districts}">
            <td th:each="cinema :${district.cinemas}" th:text="${cinema.visitor}" />
        </th:block>
      </th:block>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Thanks for your advice. I have just edited